# What is the work logic of the Mongo-Spark Connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I've been trying to understand how the mongo-spark connector works under the hood, but I'm still not getting the whole work logic behind it.

**Details**:
I'm trying to use Mongo-Spark to run a spark job to which perform mainly text search against a MongoDB collection. 
Spark and MongoDB run on two different clusters

So I created the following Spark-mongo Data frame:

```
entity_df = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
                        .option("spark.mongodb.input.database", "WikiData") \
                        .option("spark.mongodb.input.collection", "entities_slim") \
                        .load()

entity_df.cache()
df = entity_df.filter(entity_df['id'] == "Q2834810").show()
```

Does the first instruction mean that the `entities_slim` collection is being copied from the MongoDB cluster to the spark cluster and represented as a Spark DataFrame?

If yes, does this mean that the connector is just a tool that only read/write data between MongoDB and Spark?

If yes, Is there a way to create spark jobs that run MongoDB quires by the MongoDB engine? something like:

```
import pymongo
from pyspark import SparkContext

spark_rdd.map(lamda x: entities.find_one( {'id': best} ))
```

Note that executing statement `entity_df.filter(entity_df['id'] == "Q2834810").show()` runs much slower than directly querying MongoDB using `pymongo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If yes, does this mean that the connector is just a tool that only read/write data between MongoDB and Spark?

To some extent, but it doesn't mean that

> the `entities_slim` collection is being copied from the MongoDB cluster.

Selections (filters) [are converted to aggregation pipelines](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/current/scala/datasets-and-sql/):

> When using filters with DataFrames or Spark SQL, the underlying Mongo Connector code constructs an aggregation pipeline to filter the data in MongoDB before sending it to Spark

This type of behavior is in general common for data source API - where projections and selections are pushed down to the source if possible.

So going back to your concern:

> Note that executing statement entity_df.filter(entity_df['id'] == "Q2834810").show() runs much slower than directly querying MongoDB using pymongo

This is to be expected. Neither Apache Spark nor MongoDB aggregations pipelines are designed for low latency, single item queries. Both are intended for large scale, batch processing. If you need fast single item access don't use Apache Spark in the first place - this is what you have databases for.

Finally if run

> job to which perform mainly text search against a MongoDB collection.

built-in MongoDB text search capabilities (as imperfect as they are) might be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks @user6910411. I need to use spark to executes jobs that requires executing many MongoDB queries. Hence, I don't really don't want to bring any data back from MongoDB collections excepts the results of the queries. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

- Using mongodb and spark connector you can load MongoDB data into spark to leverage sparks range of API's(**Spark SQL, Spark streaming, machine learning, and graph APIs**) to perform rich aggregations to your mongodb data
- This enables you to leverage the **spark's capabilities** to analyze your data offloading to Spark
- This is **two-way connector**, you can load mongodb data into spark and spark RDD's back to MongoDB

> Does the first instruction mean that the entities_slim collection is
>   being copied from the MongoDB cluster to the spark cluster and
>   represented as a Spark DataFrame?

Yes

> If yes, does this mean that the connector is just a tool that only
>   read/write data between MongoDB and Spark?

Yes

> If yes, Is there a way to create spark jobs that run MongoDB quires by
>   the MongoDB engine?

You may need to query data from mongodb in mongodb itself? You can process your data into spark and store it back to mongodb